# How to hide form with dynamically generated ID by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have several forms with dynamically generated ID

```
<form id = "1">
    employer: <input type = "text" />
</form>

<form id = "2">
    employer: <input type = "text" />
</form>

<form id = "3">
    employer: <input type = "text" />
</form>
```

I want to create a button associated with each form so that when I click the button the form will be hidden. So the onclick function should take the id as a parameter. How to achieve this?

I tried the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputElement = document.createElement('button');
inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    hideForm(1);
});
document.body.appendChild(inputElement);
</script>
```

With hideForm defined below

```
<script>
function hideForm(id){
    $("#id").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not then I recommend you do some research.... Where are the buttons to trigger the function and since these are dynamic where do you build them? This question is very poorly planned. I suggest you update your question and include all relevant source code and explain in more detail how things currently function and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added more details. Hope that clarifies my question

Comment: @charlietfl I want to hide any form that I want. I do not know before hand what those IDs are. In my question, i simply gave an example where i try to hide the form with id = "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the ID when you have a reference to the form elemnt

for example:

```
$('form').each(function(i){
   var $form = $(this),
       $button = $('<button>',{text:'Hide form # '+(i+1)}).click(function(){
            $form.hide()
       });

   $('body').append( $button);
})
```

Comment: I think this is also a brilliant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to put the button right under each form? This solution puts all the buttons together

Comment: Sure use `after()`. I only did what was shown in question which was not very clear  http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string concatenation in jQuery selector:

```
function hideForm(id){
    $("#"+id).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are looking for.

**HTML :**

```
<form id="1">
  employer:
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Hide</button>
</form>

<form id="2">
  employer:
  <input type="text" />
  <button class="hide-button">Hide</button>
</form>

<form id="3">
  employer:
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Hide</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/pp6j8zvx/

Comment: @Zhuo : Your Welcome !